# How handle Yes No DisplayAlert in XUnitTest?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xunit

Plaese help me how to work with await DisplayAlert in XUnitTest?

LoginPageViewModel Code:

```
public ICommand LogoutCommand;

public LoginPageViewModel()
{
   LogoutCommand= new RelayCommand(LogoutExecution);
}

async void LogoutExecution()
{
   result = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert!","Are you sure you want to logout?", "Yes", "No");
   if (result)
   {
      //Code Execution
      await LogOut();
   }
}
```

XUnitTest Code :

```
public class LoginPageViewModelTest
{
        LoginViewModel loginvm;
        public LoginViewModelTest()
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Mocks.MockForms.Init();            
            var app = new Mock<App>().Object;
            app.MainPage = new Mock<Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage>().Object;
            loginvm = new LoginPageViewModel();
        }        

        [Fact]
        public void LogoutCommandExecuted()
        {
             loginvm.LogoutCommand.Execute(null);
        }
 }
```

When i Test LogoutCommandExecuted, Execution not completed after hitting this line. "await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert"

Please help me, how to execute if "App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert" in Command Execution method?

Comment: That UI/implementation concern should have been abstracted out of the viewmodel to allow greater flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

From a design perspective the view model is tightly coupled to UI concerns when it makes the `DisplayAlert` call.

Those concerns should be abstracted out to allow for better flexibility, testability and maintainability.

Take advantage of dependency inversion principles

For example, create an abstraction to represent the desired functionality

```
public interface IDialogService {
    Task<bool> DisplayAlert (String title, String message, String accept, String cancel);

    //...other members
}
```

Its implementation will basically wrap the actual UI concerns

```
public class DialogService : IDialogService {
    public Task<bool> DisplayAlert (String title, String message, String accept, String cancel) {
        return App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title,message, accept, cancel);
    }

    //...other members
}
```

The view model will explicitly depend on the service abstraction.

Also, try to avoid `async void` except for event handlers

```
public class LoginPageViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    private readonly IDialogService dialog;

    public LoginPageViewModel(IDialogService dialog) {
       LogoutCommand = new RelayCommand(LogoutExecution);
    }

    public ICommand LogoutCommand { get; private set; }

    void LogoutExecution() {
       logOut += onLogOut;
       logOut(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private event EventHdnalder logOut = delegate { };

    private async void onLogOut(object sender, EventArgs args) {
        logOut -= onLogOut;
        var result = await dialog.DisplayAlert("Alert!","Are you sure you want to logout?", "Yes", "No");
        if (result) {
          //Code Execution
          await LogOut();
       }
    }

    //...
}
```

Assuming there were no other tightly coupled dependencies, then `LoginPageViewModel` should be able to be tested in isolation without any knock on effects associated with UI concerns. Provided properly mocked dependencies are injected into the subject under test.

In production the system can be configured to use dependency services to inject service implementations into dependent classes.

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi but no code execution after "await dialog.DisplayAlert" same issue